# Php сессии Здравствуйте, user!

Tags: ulogin, php, сессия, авторизация

Некоторые проблемы возникли при подключении uLogin на свой сайт.
На сайте есть ВХОД - для пользователей, зарегистрированных на сайте и помещенных в базу.
После того, как пользователь заходит - пишется надпись: " Здравствуйте, $login".
Вот кусок кода как именно это делается:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
                <a href="#enter" class="button">Войти</a><br /> 
                <?php } else { ?>
                <div id = "user_panel">
                <p>Здравствуйте, <?=$_SESSION['user']?><br /></p>
                <a id = "submit_exit" href="#" class="button_exit">Выйти</a>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Однако - после подключения файла check.php - код взят с сайта uLogin:

```
<?php session start();

   $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   $user = json_decode($s, true);
   //$user['network'] - соц. сеть, через которую авторизовался пользователь
   //$user['identity'] - уникальная строка определяющая конкретного пользователя соц.  сети
   //$user['first_name'] - имя пользователя
   //$user['last_name'] - фамилия пользователя

   if (isset($user)) {

   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
   header('Location: index.php');
   exit;
}
?>
```

Итак - после подключения этого файла - то есть если мы теперь захотим войти через сервис uLogin - то понадобится еще и ['first_name'] - иначе будет следующая надпись:
"Здравствуйте, ARRAY", если теперь добавить сюда:

```
<p>Здравствуйте, <?=$_SESSION['user'] ['first_name']?><br /></p>
```

То надпись будет то что надо для сервиса uLogin, однако, если теперь зайти с помощью обычной регистрации на сайте - то будет следующая надпись: 
<p>Здравствуйте, "И ТУТ ТОЛЬКО ПЕРВАЯ БУКВА ЛОГИНА"</p>
В общем выводится после слова Здравствуйте при обычной авторизации только первая буква зарегистрированного логина. Что можно сделать, чтобы выводилось полное имя логина?

P.S. Файл авторизации:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once "functions.php";

    /* Получаем и обрабатываем данные */
    $login = escape($_POST['login']);
    if (strlen($login) == 0) exit;
    $password = escape($_POST['password']);
    if (strlen($password) == 0) exit;

    $password_hash = md5($password.$hash); // Создаём хеш пароля

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password_hash'");

    if ($result) {
        $arr = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if ($arr['login'] != $login) $auth = 1;
        if ($arr['password'] != $password_hash) $auth = 2;
        if ($arr['login'] == $login && $arr['password'] == $password_hash) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $arr['login'];
            $_SESSION['user_password'] = $arr['password'];
            $auth = $arr['login'];
        }
    }
    else
        $auth = 3;

    echo $auth;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неужели так сложно додуматься самому? Достаточно добавить проверку типа

```
is_array($_SESSION['user'])
```

перед выводом имени пользователя

Comment: Добавил вот так:

<div id = "user_panel">
                <p><?php is_array($_SESSION['user'])?>Здравствуйте, <?=$_SESSION['user']?><br /></p>
                <a id = "submit_exit" href="#" class="button_exit">Выйти</a>
                </div>

Ничего не изменилось. По-прежнему выводится одна буква из Логина.

Comment: Сделал вот так:
<p>Здравствуйте, <?if(is_array($_SESSION['user'])) $_SESSION['user'] ['first_name']?><br /></p>
Теперь пишется только "Здравствуйте," - то есть вообще не пишется логин.

Comment: > <?if(is_array($_SESSION['user'])) $_SESSION['user'] ['first_name']?>

Из этого условия видно, что $_SESSION['user'] не массив, если у вас ничего не выводится.

И прежде чем выводить что-то распечатайте массив > print_r($_SESSION)  и посмотрите что внутри, а дальше делайте выводы что не так.

Comment: что нужно сделать чтобы стало массивом?

Comment: @Photon,
мне просто интерестно

>Достаточно добавить проверку типа is_array($_SESSION['user'])

Как это проверка может решить проблему?

Comment: Караул.  Люди, судя по вопросам, вам вообще не место в программировании:

    if (is_array($_SESSION['user'])) 
        echo $_SESSION['user']['first_name'];
    else 
        echo $_SESSION['user'];

Comment: Могу посоветовать вам [подучить PHP][1], либо нанять программиста. Не то чтобы ваша задача была сложной, но предлагать сделать всю работу за вас, это уже наглость.


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.control-structures.php

Comment: да..я новичок. Спасибо. Теперь все работает!